# C# .NET grab data from a COM port

Tags: c#, com

How can i grab data in .NET c# from a COM port ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at System.IO.Ports

Maybe this http://www.devasp.net/net/articles/display/727.html helps you.

Answer (score 1):

For this purpose just use the [SerialPort class.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.ports.serialport.aspx)